# Java Extend Classes Over Files

Tags: java, class, extend

If I have

```
public class main
{
   public void randomFunction()
   {

      //Test Code
   }
}
```

And I wish to be able to pass this randomFunction over to another class in another file how would I be able to do this?

Comment: Well...that code wouldn't compile, for starters...

Comment: @Makoto Well it's not meant to compile it's meant so that I can figure out how to share functions and variables over multiple files and classes instead of one giant class.

Comment: Yes, but...if you're going to call a method from one class and expect it to be used in another, it should be syntatically valid.  I can't infer what you're trying to do with a `void` method that returns a `boolean`, so I can't *exactly* say.  However, there's a ton of duplicates on the matter, so I'll link one of them here.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the class and the method "static", then import this class in class B, and use your randomFunction like so:

> Main.randomFunction();

Answer (score 0):

**First**, As mentioned the following code won't compile for the first place, because you're trying to return a `boolean` value, while the function not suppose to return nothing.

**Second**,
    **If** both of the classes that you want to share this function has the same father but just have different types, than inheritance will be the solutions for you, If you haven't learn `OOP`, than now will be a good time to start.
    **Else**, if they are completely different, than making a 3rd `Utility` static class that will contain this function will be a good match, And both of the classes could use it to they disposal.